# Delete td of table htm with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

hi guys i have a question, i need remove a td of table, the td has a id and i try with remove(), but doesnt work this is my code in js

```
$('.btnEliminarLicencia').off('click');

    $('.btnEliminarLicencia').on('click', function () {
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();

            var rlim=$('.btnEliminarRemoto').parent().parent().remove('#idLicenciaClienteR');
       alert (rlim);        

    });
```

and i have two tables, in the first with the btnEliminarLicencia click remove the tr of table and in the second table delete also the td what is the first td of table , this is the code, i need delete the first table and a specific td

first table

```
<table class="table table-bordered tabla_licencia">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sucursal</th>
        <th>Codigo (ID cliente)</th>
        <th>Licencia</th>
        <th>Caducidad</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th style="width: 15%;"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td data-id="318">13123</td>
       <td id="id_Cliente">18865082</td>         
       <td>482947</td>
       <td>2016-11-04</td>
       <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" checked="" disabled="">
       </td>
       <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnEditLicencia" style="float:right;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarLicencia" style="float:left;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

second table

```
<table class="table table-bordered tabla_remoto">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Licencia</th>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Usuario</th>
        <th>Clave</th>
        <th style="width: 15%;"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td id="idLicenciaClienteR">18865082</td>
        <td>Caja</td>
        <td>883792</td>
        <td>nim3</td>      
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnEditRemoto" style="float:right;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarRemoto" style="float:left;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

in this case delete `<td id='idLicenciaClienteR'>189992887</td>`
as might do it, thanks

Comment: Just use `$('#idLicenciaClienteR').remove()`

Comment: Can you please add some more `HTML` , with you button. So that we can able to find the hierarchy of the `HTMl` structure. In you code it is simply `parents()` is confusing.

Comment: @Satpal as might make for what has to remove, 
also visually is removed

Comment: @Samir yes, this is the complete table "remoto" is a second table, give me a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you,

```
$('.btnEliminarLicencia').on('click', function () {
     $('td#idLicenciaClienteR').remove();      
});
```

Since `id` is `unique` in a page, you can dirctly use the `id`, no need to find with `.parents()`.

Comment: another query, as might make delete, only the contents of the td

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('table td#id_Cliente').remove();
```

you can also define the class by putting `.yourClass` behind table